# Use Animation Playback when frames have different names

Tags: python

My addon renders frames whose names are not constant.  How can I use Python to get the playback to work?

I'm working on a time remapping addon and wanted to give the user the option to include the true frame number in the filename, e.g.:

`1.00_0001.png`

`1.25_0002.png`

`1.50_0003.png`

But `bpy.ops.render.play_rendered_anim()` doesn't work on these, although importing these images into the Video Editor works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator doesn't expose any options you could set, but this seems to be the command it uses:

```
'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\blender.exe -a -f 24 1.0 -s 1 -e 250 -j 1 C:\\tmp\\0001.png'
```

There's even a step / frame jump parameter:

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Command_Line#Animation_Playback_Options:

But it doesn't really help in your case. You need to specify every single frame:

```
blender -a -f 24 1.0 00_0001.png 25_0002.png 50_0003.png 75_0004.png
```

Comment: That command helps.  I suppose one option would be to modify the line in the file `screen_play_rendered_anim.py` where the command `blender -a ...` is defined and then bundle the modified file with my addon.  I'll have to decide if this functionality is worth having an extra file.

Comment: You could change that script and submit to the patch tracker as proposal, to make it more generic. It could be changed to optionally accept a callback function to find the right files.